# Redirect to Paypal after completing all steps of Checkout

Tags: magento, paypal

I am using PayPal as payment method on my store in Magento.When i select PayPal as payment method it redirects me to PayPal login page at the same time but i want to redirect on that page after completing all steps of checkout.

How can i do this?
Is there any admin settings or I have to customize the code for this?
Please help.

Comment: Are you using Paypal Express or Paypal Standard checkout method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Paypal Express Checkout` is a checkout method (and not a payment method) and goes for authorisation to paypal website, get's the authorisation and user billing details and redirects you back to finish the checkout in paypal express checkout page.

This is how it works, you can set the action to be `"sale" instead of "authorisation"` but it will still redirect you back to Paypal express Checkout page in Magento to finish the order placement.

`PayPal Express` is designed to work this way (`redirect to Paypal, then redirect to your website again`). One reason is for example, that your business terms etc. must be shown to the customer before he finally agrees to buy.

There is - of course - another possibility: You could use Website `Payments Standard`. The customer will be redirected to PayPal after he confirmed your business terms and pays there. 
Bad about this: `Payments Standard` is an "old standard" and "redirects most of the time"; we see several cases where the payment is confirmed by the customer, but the `IPN` won't show in Magento backend.

**Brief Idea :**

**Sale:** – If one uses payment action as `Sale` in PayPal online payment, the amount will be automatically credited to merchant account when the order is placed successfully.
If one sets PayPal payment action as `Sale`, the order is invoiced automatically when the order is placed.

**Authorization:** – The amount is not automatically credited to merchant account when order is placed successfully. For crediting amount to merchant account, the merchant should login to PayPal account and should approve the transaction.

**PayPal Express:**
User gets redirected to PayPal directly after the payment method has been chosen (and obviously before the order has been completed).
They return to the site to complete the order after authorizing payment with PayPal.

Uses the `getCheckoutRedirectUrl()` method which gets called in the `savePayment()` action of `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController`. So you get redirected before the order is completed as described above.

**PayPal Standard:**
User goes through entire checkout process and completes the order on site. They then get redirected to PayPal to sort out payment.
They do not need to come back to the site to complete the order as it has already been completed before redirecting to PayPal.

Uses the `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()` which gets called in the `saveOrder()` method of `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage`

This is why you see the empty basket if you return to the site regardless of whether you pay at PayPal or not – `the quote has already been converted to an order`.

**So in this sense PayPal express is essentially checkout method and PayPal standard is a payment method.**

See additional information from Magento knowledge base :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/getting-started-with-paypal-express-checkout-for-magento-community

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/paypal-express-checkout-workflow-for-magento-community

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-up-paypal-express-checkout-for-magento-community

Comment: For the record: PayPal standard can redirect the user back to the originating site _after_ the authorization or payment is made (whereas express checkout normally redirects the user before the authorization or payment is made. Glad the recommendation of using Express Checkout is working for the OP; just didn't want future readers to think that Standard cannot redirect the user back.